# Labeling for Image Segmentation in Google Vertex AI

Tags: image-segmentation, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I loaded some images to label for image segmentation and looks like the option still isn't available in Vertex AI . When I select some item for labeling I don't see image and any tool that allow creating bitmap masks .

Any way to label data for Image segmentation in Vertex AI ?

Comment: "the option isn't available" means you should request support from the company.